# Excel: moving files that contain relative file references

Tags: excel, sharepoint, relative-path

When a formula in Excel refers to a cell in another file, Excel stores a relative pathname so that if you move the files the links don't break. This works as I expect when the files are stored on a network drive, but not when the files are stored in a SharePoint doc library. Any ideas why and how I can fix it?

In more detail ...

**Setup 1 (works perfectly)**

- `\\server\UserFiles$\MClarke\My Documents\Folder1\a.xlsx` includes the formula `='\\server\UserFiles$\MClarke\My Documents\Folder1\[b.xlsx]Sheet1'!$A$1`
- Move both files from Folder1 to Folder2
- Open `\\server\UserFiles$\MClarke\My Documents\Folder2\a.xlsx` and the formula automatically changes to `='\\server\UserFiles$\MClarke\My Documents\Folder2\[b.xlsx]Sheet1'!$A$1`

**Setup 2 (fails)**

- `http://intranet-server/dept/Folder1/a.xlsx` includes the formula `='http://intranet-server/dept/Folder1/[b.xlsx]Sheet1'!$A$1`
- Move both files from Folder1 to Folder2
- Open `http://intranet-server/dept/Folder2/a.xlsx` and the formula **(incorrectly)** still says `='http://intranet-server/dept/Folder1/[b.xlsx]Sheet1'!$A$1`

I have tried moving and opening files in Setup 2 with both a mapped network drive and using SharePoint's "Open with Explorer" function. Both approaches give the same undesired behaviour: the formula in the moved file continues to point to the original location of the file rather than the new location. So why would Excel store an absolute path in that case but a relative path in Setup 1?

Comment: An http path isn't the same as a file path.

Comment: You might be able to get the behavior you want in sharepoint by using the "WebDAV" path instead of the http path (assuming WebDAV is enabled in your environment)

Comment: "An http path isn't the same as a file path" -- true in general, but it is the format that Excel uses all by itself in this context. It is not that I entered that URL, but that when I enter a formula (in a.xlsx) that refers to a cell in another file (b.xlsx) the way Excel identifies the target file is using that http format.

Comment: I do not think WebDAV is used in our environment. If it were then using "Open in Explorer" would show a UNC address rather than an HTTP address and, as you say, the problem might just go away. But I don't think I have that option.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried many alternatives and eventually found that the only way to update the file references was to do so manually using the `Edit Links` dialog from the Data ribbon. That works perfectly, but is just a bit annoying.